# Delete screenshot taken by captureVisibleTab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension. How would you go about deleting images taken by captureVisibleTab? I have a fear of clogging up user storage with extraneous unused images.

Comment: Nvm. Found out that the data returned is an encoded image in itself. There is nothing saved to the file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method doesn't create physical files, it just passes you an images in data url format (as a base64 encoded string), so you don't need to worry about cleaning resourses.